# Re-positioning buttons when resizing browser

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to know if there is any way I can re-position buttons using bootstrap 5 in html or css to reposition it when I resize in browser?

For example in a full screen browser, the button is in the center. However, when I resize it, I want the button to be at the bottom.

Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap (and many other styling libraries) make use of a [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) for creating responsive designs. You can use these `col` definitions to adjust where content is as the window size changes.

Alternatively there is [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) baked directly into CSS.